# Collections: Nested Tables- data not displaying

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am working with Collections Nested Tables in SQL Developer.  When I select from a table that contains a nested table column, it only returns the container holder and not the data.
Output:
COLLECTION_USER.T_NESTED_TABLE_ADDRESS([COLLECTION_USER.T_ADDRESS],[COLLECTION_USER.T_ADDRESS])

Once I export the results. The export shows everything correctly.
Output:
 COLLECTION_USER.T_NESTED_TABLE_ADDRESS(COLLECTION_USER.T_ADDRESS('2 State Street','Beantown','MA','12345'),COLLECTION_USER.T_ADDRESS('4 Hill Street','Lost Town','CA','54321'))
Has anyone else seen this?  I think I just need to upgrade SQL Developer but I am just asking.

Answer (score 0):

From an online example since you didn't provide your source code/SQL

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE MY_TAB_T AS
       TABLE OF VARCHAR2(30);
/
CREATE TABLE NESTED_TABLE (
       ID    NUMBER,
       COL1  MY_TAB_T
)
NESTED TABLE COL1 STORE AS COL1_TAB;

INSERT INTO NESTED_TABLE VALUES (
       1,
       MY_TAB_T(
              'A'
       )
);
INSERT INTO NESTED_TABLE VALUES (
       2,
       MY_TAB_T(
              'B', 'C'
       )
);
INSERT INTO NESTED_TABLE VALUES (
       3,
       MY_TAB_T(
              'D', 'E',
              'F'
       )
);
COMMIT;

select * from nested_table;
```

[image]

If you double-click on the nested table column, you'll see a Pencil Icon, and then clicking that -

[image]

This is using version 19.4, but I'm not aware of any bugs in this area in the recent past, although my memory is usually suspect at best.